# Trouble with project - new to java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am working on a project for Uni, and I want to load file contents into local arrays which later print.

When the user chooses 1 to view the wallet, I want the program to display the crypto balance from the text file onto the console. However, my code is not doing that. I am very new to using buffered and I reverse engineered a previous assignment, so my code must be wrong.

My text file contains
"BTC 1.3426
ETH 5.2519
XRP 158.5000"

Please ignore all the // code and see the sections for `viewWallet()` and `readCryptoBalance()`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    static Scanner userInputInt = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner userInputString = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner userInputDouble = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) { //throws Exception
        int userChoice = getUserChoice();
        switch (userChoice) {
            case 1:
                viewWallet();
                break;
        }
    }

    // This method asks and returns what the user wants to do
    public static int getUserChoice() {
        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("************ Crypto Wallet **********");
        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("(1) View wallet");
        System.out.println("(2) Look up the balance of a given crypto");
        System.out.println("(3) Add new cryptos");
        System.out.println("(4) Remove an existing crypto");
        System.out.println("(5) Update wallet");
        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
        System.out.print("Please enter your choice (1, 2, 3, 4, or 5): ");
        return userInputInt.nextInt();
    }

    // This method is called for user choice 1
    public static void viewWallet() {
        double[] balance = readCryptoBalance();
        System.out.println(balance);
    }

    // This method reads and returns the crypto balances from the file
    public static double[] readCryptoBalance() {
       double[] temp = new double [100];
       int lineNumber =0;
       try{

           BufferedReader myFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("wallet.txt"));
           String sCurrentLine;
           while ((sCurrentLine = myFile.readLine()) != null){
               temp[lineNumber] =Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.split("\t")[1]);
               lineNumber++;
           }
           myFile.close();
       } catch (IOException e){
           System.out.println("I/O exception error when reading");
       }
       double[] balance = new double[lineNumber];
       System.arraycopy(temp, 0, balance, 0, lineNumber);
       return balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few mistakes (aside from missing curly braces that I added in my edit).

1. `sCurrentLine.split("\t")` - There are two errors here. The first error is that you need to escape the slash character. Therefore, the correct expression should be `"\\t"`. However, your file might not be tabbed delimited. Therefore, for space-delimited text, you should use `"\\s"`, `" "`, or `"\\s+"`. If you are not sure how many spaces, the last expression is the best because it will work with one-or-more spaces.
2. `Integer.parseInt(...)` - This needs to be `Double.parseDouble()` because the values in the file are floating-point numbers, not integers.
3. `System.out.println(balance)` inside `viewWallet()` is incorrect - That line displays the object, not the contents because arrays do not have a way to override `toString()`. So, you have to iterate through the `balance` array and display it contents. The simplest way is like this:

```
for(double value : balance) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

This will display all the values in the array in separate lines. If the array is empty, it will skip altogether.

---

### Corrected code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static Scanner userInputInt = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner userInputString = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner userInputDouble = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) { // throws Exception
        int userChoice = getUserChoice();
        switch (userChoice) {
        case 1:
            viewWallet();
            break;
        }
    }

    // This method asks and returns what the user wants to do
    public static int getUserChoice() {
        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("************ Crypto Wallet **********");
        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("(1) View wallet");
        System.out.println("(2) Look up the balance of a given crypto");
        System.out.println("(3) Add new cryptos");
        System.out.println("(4) Remove an existing crypto");
        System.out.println("(5) Update wallet");
        System.out.println("****************************************************************");
        System.out.print("Please enter your choice (1, 2, 3, 4, or 5): ");
        return userInputInt.nextInt();
    }

    // This method is called for user choice 1
    public static void viewWallet() {
        double[] balance = readCryptoBalance();
        for(double value : balance) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

    // This method reads and returns the crypto balances from the file
    public static double[] readCryptoBalance() {
        double[] temp = new double[100];
        int lineNumber = 0;
        try {

            BufferedReader myFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wallet.txt"));
            String sCurrentLine;
            while ((sCurrentLine = myFile.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
                temp[lineNumber] = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
                lineNumber++;
            }
            myFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading crypto balance: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        double[] balance = new double[lineNumber];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, balance, 0, lineNumber);
        return balance;
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: the contents of the file I created to test was exactly as the string provided by the OP (minus the double quotes) `BTC 1.3426 ETH 5.2519 XRP 158.5000`. Therefore, my solution assumed space-delimited string in a single line. Add a carriage return/line feed after each number to have distinct lines for the different crypto currency values.

Comment: After changing my code to your recommendations, everything seems to run fine, however, there is no output for the the balance, only  "I/O exception error when reading". I wonder what could be wrong and why my text file output isn't coming up?

Comment: @Ddddd12312 can you tell me what line number is failing? I assume is this line `BufferedReader myFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wallet.txt"))`

Comment: I recommend you replace your class with mine, and add (later on) the methods for choices 2 though 5. I can execute this code without I/O errors. I don't really know what could be causing it on your end. HOWEVER. to get to the bottom of it, replace the error message inside the system out with  `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`. That will tell us the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @Ddddd12312 I just made an update to the catch block that is the correct way to handle this exception (for now). I changed the filename to "wallets.txt" (no such file exist with that name), and I got the following error message "`Error reading crypto balance: wallets.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)`". That tells a more complete story of what is the nature of the error encountered.

Comment: @Ddddd12312 have you tried my suggestion of printing out the exception message? I am curious to know what is the source of your I/O error.

Comment: I have added the e.getMessage()) and it spits out "wallet.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)". I really appreciate the help! It Just looks like I have the text document implemented incorrectly! @hfontanez

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I managed to get it work by copying the whole file path in. Again, thank you!

Comment: @Ddddd12312 Do not hard-copy the whole path. That is a bad implementation. Use system variables or relative paths. What is your hard-coded path?

Comment: "C:\\Users\\James\\IdeaProjects\\A3_591158\\src\\com\\company\\wallet.txt"

Comment: In Windows, `C:\Users\XYZ` can be resolved using a system property called "user.home", where _XYZ_ is the folder for the current user. That looks like `String path = System.getProperty("user.home")`. This is often preferred. It has it's drawbacks because it assumes that every user has the file. So, that brings us to the next point: Don't use personal folders to put resources your program uses. Either use a folder all users have access to, or use folders inside your project and refer to them using relative paths.

Comment: Hard-coding paths is also a bad idea because, if you need to port your program to another computer, that exact path must also exist in the new system. This is why using folders inside your project and referring to them using relative paths is almost always a better alternative.

Comment: Lastly, that path only works on Windows systems. If your new environment is Linux of Mac, your path won't work.

Comment: I appreciate the further tips! I will implement those changes. Again, thank you for your help! I was stuck and you helped me out a lot